# Get the list of installed packages by user in R

Tags: r, package

How we can get the list of installed packages by user in R along with its version?

I know about the command `installed.packages()` which will give information about all packages (base or non-base). But how we can get those installed by user to have something like this:

```
Package    Version
X          3.01
Y          2.0.1
Z          1.0.2
```

For all **user** installed packages (i.e. those package you installed via `install.packages("X")`)

Comment: perhaps useful http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/List-of-default-packages-that-come-with-R-td4661857.html

Comment: This is the first link I got after googling 'r installed user packages': <http://www.r-bloggers.com/list-of-user-installed-r-packages-and-their-versions/>. And does exactly what you want.

Comment: Do you mean just the `non-base` packages?

Comment: Try `x <- installed.packages(); x[ is.na(x[,"Priority"]), c("Package", "Version")]`

Answer (score 85):

[ref](https://www.r-bloggers.com/list-of-user-installed-r-packages-and-their-versions/)

```
ip = as.data.frame(installed.packages()[,c(1,3:4)])
ip = ip[is.na(ip$Priority),1:2,drop=FALSE]
ip
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the one provided by @Ckkhamari above?  (the code above is : `str(allPackage <- installed.packages(.Library, priority = "high")); allPackage [, c(1,3:5)]` .  It gives a very different list of packages.  The "ref" link does not explain anything.

Answer (score 44):

I just found another ways to see the list of the packages without writing any code:

- Open RStudio
- Navigate to `Help --> R Help` (from the menu above)
- You will see the help panel opened.
- Then follow, `Reference --> Packages`

There you are.

---

OR

- Open R console
- Navigate to `Help --> Html help`
- Then follow, `Reference --> Packages`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it also tells you in what directory the packages are installed, under the user that is logged in.

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk no it shouldn't. OP is asking for a base R way, not IDE-secificway.

Answer (score 14):

```
str(allPackage <- installed.packages(.Library, priority = "high"))

allPackage [, c(1,3:5)]
```

You will get all the active package List

Answer (score 10):

Here's my solution.

```
tibble::tibble(
  Package = names(installed.packages()[,3]),
  Version = unname(installed.packages()[,3])
)
```

You can even filter some packages that you want to show.

```
pkg = tibble::tibble(
  Package = names(installed.packages()[,3]),
  Version = unname(installed.packages()[,3])
)

dplyr::filter(pkg, Package %in% c("tibble", "dplyr"))
```

Answer (score 4):

If I develop an app or model and want to record the package versions used, I call `sessionInfo()`

Comment: [`sessionInfo()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/sessionInfo.html) answers a subtly different question.  It displays the *attached* and *loaded* packages, which is a subset of the *installed* packages on a machine.  And `sessionInfo()` certainly won't help an admin enumerate the packages installed for other users (because their session isn't even active).

Comment: `sessionInfo()` is useful when saving a dependencies file. This is my main use of the function and is not from an administrator's point-of-view.

Comment: @Seanosapien it may be your main use of the function but it is not what OP is asking

Answer (score 2):

One trick would be to use `library()` and a window with all the packages will pop up