# Differentiate among packages installed through CRAN and Bioconductor [R]

Tags: r, environment, cran, bioconductor, reproducible-research

I installed a bunch of R packages in a conda environment and I want to create something similar to `conda env export` does, but in R.

You can obtain package name and versioning from ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40120266/7580614)):

```
ip = as.data.frame(installed.packages()[,c(1,3:4)])
ip = ip[is.na(ip$Priority),1:2,drop=FALSE]
ip
```

.. but is there any way of knowing which repo each package is coming?
(And then to install all packages in a row through `install.packages(c("pck1", "pck2"...))` for CRAN-based or `BiocManager::install(c("pck1", "pck2"...))` for bioconductor-based ones.)

Comment: `sessioninfo::session_info()` provides something like that.

Comment: Maybe use `renv` to create a lockfile which includes repo details. [Vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html)

Comment: `BiocManager::install()` also installs CRAN packages so that for the use case outlined it is not necessary to know where they come from. Also `ap = available.packages(repos = BiocManager::repositories())` has a column for `Package` and `Repository` so the source repository can be determined before installation, or by the join between installed and available packages.

Comment: Thanks all. @MartinMorgan, I can accept if you post the response as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BiocManager::install()` also installs CRAN packages so that for the use case outlined it is not necessary to know where they come from. Also `p = available.packages(repos = BiocManager::repositories())` has a column for Package and Repository so the source repository can be determined before installation, or by the join between installed and available packages